# copy bulleted text from word to html text area

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

so when i try to copy the bullet-ed  text from word and paste it to html textarea it shows only text and no bullets is showing. is there any way i can do it. May be using java script or any other method.

and also i only want to use textarea and no text editor like ckeditor,etc.

it's as simple like this is my word text

Some Text

Some Text

but when i paste it in text area it is just

Some Text

Some Text

i think javascript can help..but i m unable to get the contents of clipboard..and even if some how i get it will the bullets be detected by javascript so that i can replace them with li tag....any help...!!!

Comment: best option is  - you can use **CKEditor** or **TinyMCE**

Answer (score 1):

Css can help with that, using `<ul>  <li>` tags...reference here

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp

Answer (score 1):

You cannot copy the bullets from word or other editor. You can try to make it an `<ul>` with `<li>` where every `<li>` means a bulleted row. you have change to HTML at any editor

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that might also work for you.

```html
<li><span>• </span><span>Some Text</span></li>
<li><span>• </span><span>Some Text</span></li>
```

This will render the bullet points now twice, so I hided the other one again using CSS like this:

```css
li :first-child {
  position: relative;
}

li :first-child::before  {
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white; // choose the color that matches your current background
}
```

**Disclaimer**:

That workaround requires manual setting of the background. Also it adds some left padding to your text. But the good thing is that you could even place other characters like "-" into the hidden content and it will make it into your clipboard.